# Testing DNS glue records for hidden nameservers that aren't live yet

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, glue-record

How do I test the glue records for a nameserver that isn't live yet?

I am more than happy testing glue records for domains that are live.

This time however we have just started the roll out of a large number of new nameservers.  While we have created the glue records via the registrar's I am struggling to find a way to test the glue records without actually assigning them to a domain.  Is this possible?

For clarification using real data (as of the time of writing)...

One of our current nameservers is `ns12.dogsbodyhosting.net.` so running a `dig -t a @g.gtld-servers.net. ns12.dogsbodyhosting.net.` correctly tells us that `g.gtld-servers.net.` cannot give as an ANSWER but that the AUTHORITY we need to speak to is `ns12.dogsbodyhosting.net.` and the ADDITIONAL (Glue) information we need of A and AAAA records.  All good :-)

The problem: We have just created `ns12.dogsdns.net.` (as well as around 40 other new nameservers) and want to test that the glue for `ns12.dogsdns.net.` exists on the `g.gtld-servers.net.` and the other `.net` servers.  However running `dig -t a @g.gtld-servers.net. ns12.dogsdns.net.` only shows us the glue records for the old DNS curently mapped to this domain and not the glue for `ns12.dogsdns.net.` that we are after.

To restate; We have created the glue records via the registrar but have no way of knowing if the registrar has done anything or if we made a typo entering all the records. So, how to we test these glue records without putting a domain live and hoping?

Even if we set up a burner domain using the new nameservers we would couldn't add all 60 nameservers to one domain.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Comment: I should add that newdns.net & olddns.net are example domains.  I didn't want to use example.com and example.net as the tld was important in this context.

Comment: So it is impossible to really help you. Too bad. You should at least obfuscate using RFC2606 and RFC5737 (but then impossible to troubleshoot your problem), this is just a mess.

Comment: Fair call on RFC5737, I'll update.  I think my example of a query that doesn't work has confused things.  All I want to know is how do I test the glue records for a nameserver that isn't live yet?  :-)

Comment: If you query the registry authoritative nameservers for your glue record and A or AAAA type you should get an authoritative reply with the info in the additional section, otherwise you get an upward referral or an error (if no glue record). PS: I recommend using `dig` to troubleshoot DNS issues instead of any other tool. Also the online https://dnsviz.net/ very useful DNS troubleshooting tool has a "Servers" tab where it will clearly show if there is glue or not. See http://dnsviz.net/d/ovh.net/servers/ for an example.

Comment: What you have described is absolutely fine and correct for testing the glue records on a live server but still doesn't seem to work for a hidden/not yet live nameserver.  I have now updated the question with REAL data and exact queries using `dig` showing what I mean :-)  I hope this helps.

Comment: Does not make any sense. A glue record is at parent. You either have created (through the registrar) this glue record or not. It is irrelevant if it is then used by some domains or not. It exists or does not exist at registry. Thanks for your update if I have time I may try to post a second answer with the new data.

Comment: Is it actually the glue record that you want to test, or do you want to test that the nameservers will work properly once you change the glue records? The former, as @PatrickMevzek says, makes little sense. The latter makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Exactly, I have created the glue records via the registrar but have no way of knowing if the registrar has done anything or if we made a typo entering all the records. So, how to we test these glue records without putting a domain live and hoping?

Comment: Since `dogsdns.net` does not use `ns12.dogsdns.net` as nameserver, this can not be a glue (except if it would also be used by some `.com` domain since the same registry handles both TLDs, but that would not be a good idea), and hence will not be published at registry (even if the registrar sends the command). It seems you use the word glue for something slightly different, I am not sure to parse "only shows us the glue records for the old DNS curently mapped to this domain and not the glue for ns12.dogsdns.net. that we are after."

Comment: BTW, sneaky way to do things (that I absolutely not recommend, you will probably create more problems than solutions, but this is often the cases with glue records): set domain `domain.example` with all its glue records `ns1.domain.example`, etc. then create `anotherdomain.example` and rename all previous hosts objects (through your registrar) to be subordinate of the new domain. This needs a competent and willing registrar  and may not be possible in all registries. Anyway, this is mostly for fun...

Answer (score 0):

The [Zonemaster](https://zonemaster.iis.se/) tool has the ability to do this. As long as the servers-to-be are up on the net and responding to queries, you can have Zonemaster use a manually provided list of nameservers instead of what is live in the DNS tree. Look for "Pre-delegated domain check".

Answer (score -1):

You check the nameservers domain is delegated to using whois:

```
vesemir:~> whois  dogsdns.net 
   Domain Name: DOGSDNS.NET
   Registry Domain ID: 2251702894_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.meshdigital.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.meshdigital.com
   Updated Date: 2018-04-13T15:27:19Z
   Creation Date: 2018-04-13T15:27:19Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2019-04-13T15:27:19Z
   Registrar: Mesh Digital Limited
   Registrar IANA ID: 1390
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email:
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone:
   Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
   Name Server: NS10.DOGSBODYHOSTING.NET
   Name Server: NS11.DOGSBODYHOSTING.NET
   Name Server: NS12.DOGSBODYHOSTING.NET
   Name Server: NS13.DOGSBODYHOSTING.NET
   Name Server: NS14.DOGSBODYHOSTING.NET
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2018-04-18T19:43:16Z <<<
[-- CUT --]
```

Clearly dogsdns.net is delegated to nameservers in DIFFERENT domain and this is very likely the reason why you do not see glue records. They will likely show up when you change the delegation. Try to add one of the new nameservers and check what happens.

Comment: I feel you didn't read the question! :-)

Comment: "You check the nameservers domain is delegated to using whois:" certainly not. You never start DNS troubleshooting with whois queries...